# CXF with OData v4 (Olingo)

Tags: cxf, odata

Could anybody tells me whether CXF has support for OData v4?

I know it's being using [Olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/) in order to provide partial support for OData v2.

I've took a look, however, it's not clear to me whether CXF is working for providing a full OData v4 support...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OData V4 library is not depending on CXF or any other framework to work. It only needs a HttpServletRequest to evaluate and a HttpServletResponse to write into.

Here is the technical servlet they use for integration testing: https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata4/blob/bfeab37b1b51d6587e2e6f280f549944d146cb1c/lib/server-tecsvc/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/server/tecsvc/TechnicalServlet.java

As you can see the library is contained in the OData object and the handling is done in the ODataHttpHandler.